# Adding correct coordinates to map using QGIS

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinates, qgis-2

I've been trying to add correct coordinates to my grid in GIS.

I have a map of the Iberian Peninsula using an Open source layer from OSM/Stamen (CRS: EPSG:3857. WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator) and while in the print composer, after adding the grid this is what iI get:

[image: Map I created in Print Composer]

Now, these coordinates do not make any sense to me. I know that they are related to the Interval units and offset but I am quite unsure how to apply correct coordinates on my map. So please tell me how to correct the showing coordinates!

[image: Size of the map]

Comment: You want the coordinates in lat/long degrees?

Comment: please explain why the coordinates you have are not "correct"

Comment: @IanTurton In the Iberia Peninsula latitude should be, in decimals, around 35 and 43. Longitude should be between 0 and -10 which is not happening. The values in the grid make no sense to me, but maybe there's something about them that I don't understand... Perhaps i'm using the wrong CRS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your grid coordinates are in the map projection by default, so in your case, they are in meters from the Equator and Greenwich.

If you look under `Draw "Grid 1" grid` you will see a button for `CRS` if you change this to EPSG:4326 your grid will be in degrees.

[image]